# Inherited ASP.NET code that connects to OD not working when connected to AD

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, ldap

I've inherited a piece of software that connects to our Open Directory to provide web authentication. When connected to the OD it works like a charm but we want to transition to using Active Directory as our main authentication provider.

Obviously there are differences in the LDAP scheme between the two and I've spent the last 6 hours googling and reading but I'm still in a bit over my head. When you try to login to the [web interface](http://cl.ly/Grgo) this is the error that is shown (this is what the web interface looks like http://cl.ly/Grgo);

Exception Details:

> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: An operations
>   error occurred.
>   [DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072020): An operations error occurred.]
>   LBOX.Membership.LDAPMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password) in c:\Program
>   Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\users.lbox.com\WorkingDirectory\LDAPMembershipProvider\LDAPMembershipProvider.cs:59
>   LBUserService.Login.loginButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Program
>   Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\users.lbox.com\WorkingDirectory\LBUserService\Login.aspx.cs:21
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +115
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +140
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981

It obviously has something to do with line 59 of `LDAPMembershipProvider.cs` and my `web.config` file.

The `web.config` file from CruiseControl.net

```
<membership defaultProvider="LDAP">
  <providers>
    <add name="LDAP" 
         type="LBOX.Membership.LDAPMembershipProvider" 
         LDAPRoot="LDAP://10.0.1.19:389/cn=administrator,cn=users,dc=office,dc=lbox,dc=com" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

line 59 from `LDAPMembershipProvider.cs`

```
// Attempt to log into the LDAP server as this user
DirectoryEntry root2 = new DirectoryEntry(LDAPRoot, distinctName, password, AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind);
DirectorySearcher searcher2 = new DirectorySearcher(root2);
searcher2.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
searcher2.Filter = String.Format("cn={0}", username);
```

I'm almost positive it has something to do with how I'm connecting to the AD using `LDAP://` I've tried but I'm unable to connect. Any help would be appreciated even if its just guesses. Ideas are to allow the AD to authenticate username and passwords without being bound.

Answer (score 1):

That `LDAPRoot` path in your `web.config` looks a bit fishy to me - it seems to denote a actual **user**:

```
LDAPRoot="LDAP://10.0.1.19:389/cn=administrator,cn=users,dc=office,dc=lbox,dc=com"
                               ****************
                               User "administrator"
```

But shouldn't that be some sort of a **container** instead? When authenticating a user, I would assume the LDAP membership provider will have to look up the user knocking on your digital doors inside an LDAP container to see if he/she is valid (or not).

You're creating a directory searcher based on that LDAP root - and searching *within a user* doesn't typically return any results....

I would try to use

```
LDAPRoot="LDAP://10.0.1.19:389/cn=users,dc=office,dc=lbox,dc=com"
```

This would just search inside the `cn=users` container, and promises more chance of a result, I hope!

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. this works to connect to the OpenDirectory LDAP
`<add name="LDAP" type="LBOX.Membership.LDAPMembershipProvider" LDAPRoot="LDAP://10.0.1.6:389/cn=users,dc=fileserver,dc=office,dc=lbox,dc=com" />`

Is there a scheme change in the same line if I want it to connect to a Windows 2008 R2 Active Directory?

the hostname of the AD is `winvm1` the domain is `office.lbox.com`

Comment: I would try: `LDAPRoot="LDAP://winvm1/cn=users,dc=office,dc=lbox,dc=com"` - I removed the IP and port, plus the `dc=fileserver` from your LDAP string - does it work?